# multiple array in a for loop need to output with json

Tags: php, arrays, json, for-loop, foreach

I have a for loop that outputs two arrays in a json_decode(); and I was wondering how I can get the first array's data, or the second's array data only.

```
for($i = 0; $i < $node_count; $i++)
{

    $results[$i] = curl_multi_getcontent  ( $curl_arr[$i]  );
    $results[$i] = json_decode($results[$i],true);

}
```

I get $results[0] and $results[1].

I can output only the $results[0]

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($results[0]);
echo "</pre>";
```

This gives me no error and I was able to output only the first array. However, when I tried this

```
foreach($results[0] as $result){
    $result['data']['id'];  
}
```

It gives me an error of undefined index. But if I tried without the `[0]`

```
foreach($results as $result){
    $result['data']['id'];  
}
```

This outputs the id in both arrays, but I'm only trying to get one array. Why is this happening?

Thanks!

EDIT:

```
   array(
      array(
         'data' => array('id' => ...),
          ....
      ),
      ...
    )



    array(
      array(
         'data' => array('id' => ...),
          ....
      ),
      ...
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

`$results[0]` is the first element of array `$results`, they are not the same thing.

**Edit:**

`$results` is something like

```
array(
  array(
     'data' => array('id' => ...),
      ....
  ),
  ...
)
```

`$results[0]` is someting like

```
  array(
     'data' => array('id' => ...),
      ....
  )
```

Comment: how come I'm able to print_r($results[0])? What would I use in the foreach?

Comment: Thanks for your response, But what if I have results[0] and results[1] that outputs and I only want to get values from the first array? I edited my post showing the two arrays

Comment: @andrewliu So you can just use `$results[0]['data']['id']`.

Comment: what if there's an array within data? I'm trying to do a foreach loop to get all the values. But it seems like foreach is not working with [0]? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @andrewliu `foreach` is not so hard thing. Did you read the manual http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
echo $results[0]['data']['id'];
echo $results[1]['data']['id'];
```

Comment: Yeah I can do that, but theres multiple id's within data so thats why I'm trying to do a foreach loop